# How can i make items of recyclerView in center?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to keep the items in center of recyclerview.  i have posted an image. please help me to do that

the code of layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/service_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/washingmachin"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/service_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Washing Mashing"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

i want the image of fridge ac laundry and all to keep in center of screen

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 0):

add

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

to your LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

set android:gravity="center" to you text view or linear layout both should work